# Equivalent of sectionIndex in Neos

Tags: neoscms

In TYPO3, if I need to create a menu for the different elements inside a page, I use the sectionIndex property. With Neos, how can I build a navigation for the elements inside a page?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, right out of the box.

That would require all elements on the page that you want to link to to have an `ID` attribute. In TYPO3 CMS all of the elements rendered with `css_styled_content` had one.

However there are multiple ways to do it with custom content elements. Like creating a section wrapper element with title and anchor id, wrap every section in such element and then create a custom content element that will look-up all of your section wrappers and make a list of anchor links pointing to sections.